# Equal height columns, with defined aspect ratio, and vertically centered content?

Tags: css

I have equal height columns with centered content:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzKwgE

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item item-first">
    <p>First</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-second">
    <p>Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-third">
    <p>Third</p>
  </div>
</div>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont {
  width: 70%;
  display: table;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33%;
}
.item-first {
  background: blue;
}
.item-second {
  background: green;
}
.item-third {
  background: blue;
}
```

[image]

This is working great. However I also need my columns to have a 16x9 aspect ratio. In rare cases there will be a lot of content, in which case its OK to change the aespect ratio.

Ive got this working below however it stops the content being vertically centered:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbyWMj

```
* {
  box-siing: border-box;
}
.cont {
  width: 70%;
  display: table;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33%;
}
.item:before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; // 16:9 ratio
  display: block;
  content: '';
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
}
.item-first {
  background: blue;
}
.item-second {
  background: green;
}
.item-third {
  background: blue;
}
```

[image]

I can see that this is happening due to the padding hack. Is there a way to have equal height columns, vertically centered content, and the 16x9 aspect ratio?

Im supporting IE9. Ideally it would look the same, but a usable fallback is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` and `vertical-align` on the elements inside each item. Try this:

```
.item {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}
.item:before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  display: inline-block; 
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
.item p {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:20px;
}
```

[**Codepen Update**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzKmzX)